# Mysql database update with ajax php not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update mysql database table with button click. But database is not getting updated...

**HTML Code :**

```
<tr >
<td>Advt Heading :</td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="idnew" id="idnew" value="<?=$member_data['id']?>"> //retrieved from mysql database 

<input type="text" name="advt_headingnew" id="advt_headingnew" value="<?=stripslashes($member_data['advt_heading']);?>" /> //retrieved from mysql database ...**I want to edit its previus retreived value...and update database**

<input name="submit" type="button" id="submit" value="Update" />

</td>
</tr>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#submit').click(function(){
var advt_headingnew = $("#advt_headingnew").val();
var idnew = $("#idnew").val();


$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'update-advt-heading.php',
     data: "advt_headingnew="+advt_headingnew+"&idnew="+idnew,

     success:function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }

 });
});
});


</script>
```

**PHP - `update-advt-heading.php` CODE :**

```
<?
$user_name = "databaseusername";
$password = "databasepassword";
$database = "databasename";
$server = "localhost";

mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database);

$heading = $_POST['advt_headingnew'];
$id=$_POST["idnew"];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


   $queryStr = "UPDATE tablename SET advt_heading='$heading' WHERE id='$id'";
    if ( mysql_query($qyeryStr)){
        return "success!";
    }else{
        return "failed!";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You are not sending `submit` value through ajax that's why your `if` condition fails. As a NOTE: Don't use `mysql` extension as it is depricated and not even supported in php7. You should use `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js code to this

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#submit').click(function(){
           var advt_headingnew = $("#advt_headingnew").val();
           var idnew = $("#idnew").val();
           var submitval = $(this).val();

           $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url:'update-advt-heading.php',
             data: "advt_headingnew="+advt_headingnew+"&idnew="+idnew+"&submit="+submitval,

             success:function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
             }

          });
       });
   });
```

Comment: Are you getting all values correctly through ajax in php script ??

Comment: try changing `<?` to `<?=` or `<?php`

Comment: got it you misspelled `$queryStr` in `mysql_query(..)`

Comment: what i think ....update_advt_heading.php is not getting value of advt_headingnew and idnew...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112579/discussion-between-garvit-mangal-and-dr-manish-joshi).

Comment: Use `echo "success!";` and `echo "failed!";` in your script. `return` isn't doing what you think it's doing. You should read up on what `return` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
var advt_headingnew = $("#advt_headingnew").val();
var idnew = $("#idnew").val();
```

To

```
var advt_headingnew = document.getElementsByName("advt_headingnew")[0].value;
var idnew = document.getElementsByName("idnew")[0].value;
```

**NOW IT IS WORKING..**